# Заработает ли Intel C++ Compiler на AMD процессоре?

Tags: c++, компилятор

Кто нибудь устанавливал его не на процессоры семейства `Intel`?

Comment: А что б ему не заработать? Или вопрос об эффективности кодогенерации для не-интеловских процессоров?

Comment: @klopp, вообще вопрос как таковой, к примеру если ПО скомпилировано на AMD, какова его эффективность на Intel процессорах?

Comment: Ну, по слухам, и некоторым тестам :) всё ровно наоборот: интеловский компилятор неплохо генерит код в первую очередь под интеловские же процессоры, независимо от платформы, под которой он это делает. Вот, например, [Abbyy](http://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/103447/) развлекались.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMD и Intel базируются на одной архитектуре x86 или amd64. Хотя в новейших процессорах у них и могут быть разночтения в наборе команд, большая часть оных одинакова. Разумеется никто в здравом уме не станет использовать такие инструкции, которые не позволят запускать компилятор на процессоре конкурента. Это потеря рынка равноценна экономическому самоубийству, учитывая тот факт, что компилятор от Intel, мягко говоря, не на ведущих ролях. Таким образом ответ на вопрос - да, заработает и по другому быть не может.

Генерирует ли компилятор от Intel такой код, что он будет быстрее на Intel? Лучше этот вопрос адресовать разработчикам от Intel, но вероятность этого есть, хотя и небольшая.

Comment: Linpack на Xeon-ах  (какие точно, не помню) собранный icc оказался  немного быстрее, чем собранный gcc (по крайней мере такое было пару лет назад).

Comment: @avp, я думаю вопрос скорее в том, будет ли код сгенерированный icc работать быстрее на процессорах Intel, чем на процессорах AMD. То, что какие-то преимущества icc имеет перед gcc/clang/msvc, не вызывает сомнений - иначе бы его не было вообще.

Comment: Код сгенерированный icc будет работать быстрее на intel, т.к. вначале бинарника, идет проверка а поддерживается скажем avx-128, поддерживается AVX-512 и т.п., и эти проверки рассчитаны только на процы от Intel, и CPU от amd64 работает как generic-x86_64, т.е. с каким-нибудь SSE1 и все. См. http://www.osnews.com/story/22683/Intel_Forced_to_Remove_quot_Cripple_AMD_quot_Function_from_Compiler_

Comment: @user1034749, по ссылке история за 2010 год, вы которой упоминается давления закона на Интел, может всё не так плохо сейчас? А если это так, то компилятор от intel использовать для массового софта это преступление.

Comment: Надеятся не стоит, у меня например icc 2013, если посмотреть дизасемблер (после компиляции -axAVX), то можно увидеть cpuid инструкцию, а потом сравнение с cmpl   $0x756e6547, это как раз 'Genu','ineI'. А AMD вернет 'AuthenticAMD' и он в пролете с AVX.

Answer (score 1):

ICC включает в свои исполняемые файлы проверку - на интел проце пойдет со всеми оптимизациями, а на не-интеле пойдет вообще без.
Если эту проверку вырубить, врубить только допустимые аппаратные расширения типа sse2 есть вероятность, что вполне хороший код получится.
Как ее отрубать я где-то видел, посмотрите в генту-вики.